# How to create a tr/td html element with angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a tr with a nested td in angular. The angular way of doing this is to use angular.element('<tr>'). And it works for all elements - except tr or td. for these two guys the call returns an empty array.

By the way it only behaves this way with jqLite. If the full blown jQuery is present everything works just fine

What am I doing wrong and how to create an TR element with jqLite?

Comment: are you writing a directive, or are you just trying to iterate over some elements and display them in a table?

Comment: The answer to your question is `<tr><td></td></tr>` since angular views are HTML. I'm assuming that you have a different question though?

Comment: @lpiepiora Yes, I am. I am trying to add support for tables to ng-scroll directive (https://github.com/Hill30/NGScroller) and I need to add a couple of TR to an existing table.

Comment: @Jon7 I need to add tr programmatically, so I need to create a new element with angular.element (or something else) and .append() it to the proper place in the existing html. Try to call angular.element('<tr></tr>') it comes back empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I posted the question an idea on how to solve it hit me. I tried and it worked. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
function createTRElement() {
  var table = angular.element('<table><tr></tr></table>');
  return table.find('tr');
}
```

The reason I like it better than the one by @lpiepiora is that it leaves it to angular to worry about cross browser interop

Answer (score 4):

You could go with a plain old `document.createElement` it is [pretty well supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html).

Consider this simple directive as an example:

```
myApp.directive('rowAppender', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var tableBody = angular.element(element).parent();
      for(var i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td0 = angular.element(document.createElement('td')).html('Element Value' + i);
        var td1 = angular.element(document.createElement('td')).html('Element Value' + i);
        angular.element(tr).append(td0).append(td1);
        tableBody.append(tr);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Check out this working Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PqjzlBYXyzOl4Xuk89rG